# ¿Qué valor toma isAlive(), cuando finaliza un proceso?

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer

Cuando esta vivo un proceso `isAlive` toma el valor de `True`
pero cuando ese proceso finaliza que valor toma?

Cuando codifico `if t.isAlive == True:` si funciona porque esta vivo el proceso
pero cuando `if t.isAlive == False:` no hace nada

Supongo que el proceso devuelve `False` al terminar el proceso
que es lo que yo necesito para realizar x acción.
o existe otra instrucción o forma de saber cuando finaliza el proceso?
gracias

```
from threading import Timer
opcion = -1
def motor01():
    print ("fin motor 1\n")

def motor02():
    print ("fin motor 2\n")

while (opcion !=0 ):
    opcion = int (input("opcion deseada "))
    if opcion == 1:
        t = Timer(10.0, motor01)
        t.start() # after 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed
        if t.isAlive()== False:
            print ("realizar una acción cuando isAlive() detecte fin de proceso")
    if opcion == 2:
        t = Timer(10.0, motor02)
        t.start() # after 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed
        if t.isAlive() == False:
            print ("realizar una acción cuando isAlive() detecte fin de proceso")
```

Comment: El método siempre va a retornar True con ese código. La llamada a isalive se produce siempre inmediatamente después de iniciar el hilo. Para poder ayudarte mejor, deberías explicar cual es la lógica que quieres que tenga tu programa, si quieres no lanzar el hilo si hay algún "motor" en funcionamiento funcionamiento por ejemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Según la documentación de Python3x, la función a llamar es `is_alive()`, `isAlive()` viene de versiones anteriores  y todavía puede usarse pero te recomendaría que uses la primera:

> **is_alive()** Return whether the thread is alive.
>
> This method returns True just before the run() method starts until
>   just after the run() method terminates. The module function
>   enumerate() returns a list of all alive threads.

Es decir, retornará `True` mientras el `Timer` este activo.

Más allá de esto, con respecto a tu código, un comentario: Estás configurando siempre la misma variable para cada `Timer`, por lo que el `t.is_alive()` siempre será el del último `Timer` instanciado. Si la idea es que dentro de un ciclo se instancien varios `Threads` y necesitas verificar cada uno para saber si está activo, debieras manejarlo todo con una lista o un diccionario.